# Change div's background color to random with mouseover and keep divs squre and flex within a container

Tags: flexbox, background-color, mouseover

I am trying to change background color of a div when mouseover. I can do that by assigning class to the div and in CSS assign background color to that class. But when trying to have background change randomly a have to change the background directly and that is where I fail. Function randomColor returns correct hex string but it is not reflected by using target.style.backgroundColor = '${randomColor()}'.

The other issue is with flexbox (I should not use Grid) where I want user set amount of divs to flex within fixed dimension square container and keep square.

When using target.style.backgroundColor = '${randomColor()}' I don't see it change color of the div which is what I expected to happen.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kubais/csj3dmrz/3/)

```
const container = document.querySelector('#container');

function addDivStart() {
    for (let i=1; i<=289; i++) {
        
        const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        // newDiv.textContent = "x";
        newDiv.setAttribute("class", "newDiv");
        container.appendChild(newDiv);

        newDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', e => e.target.classList.add('my-color-class') );
    }
}
addDivStart();

function removeAllChildNodes(parent) {
    while (parent.firstChild) {
        parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild);
    }
}

let rows;

function randomColor (colorHex) {
    colorHex =  "#" + (Math.random()    * 0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
    console.log(colorHex);
    return colorHex;
}

function addDivSettings() {
    for (let i=1; i<=rows; i++) {
    
        const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        // newDiv.textContent = "x";
        newDiv.setAttribute("class", "newDiv");
        container.appendChild(newDiv);

        newDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', e => e.target.style.backgroundColor = '${randomColor()}'); //to have random color
        // newDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', e => e.target.classList.add('my-color-class') ); // to change only to red
        
    }
}

button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    rows = prompt('Enter desired number of squares per side (max 100):', 17);
    rows = rows * rows
    console.log(rows);

    removeAllChildNodes(container)

    addDivSettings();
    
})
```